# Alloy ListView not showing

Tags: appcelerator

So, I'm going nuts with this one. Using latest 5.2.0GA, I'm not able to get the Alloy ListView to show on Android. In iOS, it shows fine, but when I run the same in an Android emulator (4.1.1 and also 5.0) as well as an android device (4.4.2) the ListItem(s) all show blank. If I add a HeaderView/FooterView they show but not the ListItem.

Going back to basics, using code from the docs, same thing.

```
Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <ListView id="elementsList">
        <ListSection name="elements">
            <ListItem title="Hydrogen"/>
            <ListItem title="Helium"/>
            <ListItem title="Lithium"/>
            <ListItem title="Beryllium"/>
            <ListItem title="Boron"/>
            <ListItem title="Carbon"/>
            <ListItem title="Nitrogen"/>
            <ListItem title="Oxygen"/>
            <!-- Abbreviated... -->
        </ListSection>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

iOS shows it as expected, Android shows only an empty white space.

What am I missing that is head-hurting obvious? I've installed Android SDK 4.0 as well as that's a minimum version for 5.2.0GA.

Thanks

Comment: Believe I have resolved it in the end. All down to styles and colors. I removed the white background from the window and the ListItem text appeared so looks like default Android colors need changing. Easy to override.

Comment: Correct, the default Android theme has a dark background with light text. So indeed if you set the Window to have a light background you won't see the text.

Answer (score 2):

I have tired changing the color of the items and it works fine. The list items appears without any problem.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ListView id="list" >
            <ListSection name="elements" >
                <ListItem title="Hydrogen" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Helium" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Lithium" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Beryllium" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Boron" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Carbon" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Nitrogen" color="black"/>
                <ListItem title="Oxygen" color="black"/>
            </ListSection>
        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure this out on my code and the whole time the font was white on a white background.. Thanks android!! (crap)